# Typescript vs javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I am trying to take some javascript and translate it into typescript in order to use it with a webpage that will utilize Aurelia. I am having some syntax issues with the below lines. If anyone  can point me in the right direction on this would be most appreciated. Lines are below. Thanks in advance

--Jason

```
//trying to see if the browser supports HTML5 FileReader functionality
//VS currently says filereader does not exist on type 'Window'
      if (window.filereader) 

//VS says Property 'trigger' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
      document.getElementById('fileBox').trigger('click');

//VS says Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'
       document.querySelector('.fileCont span').click(function () {
    this.remove();
});


  // Property 'file' does not exist on type 'HTMLImageElement'
     var img = document.createElement("img");
     img.file = file;
```

Comment: You have to install the [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) you need

Comment: Also, what is in your tsconfig? What is the target? That may include DOM types already. Also what editor are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio . I don't see a tsconfig.json within my application . However, I do have multiple tsconfig.json files in my Visual Studio Program Files directories like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web\Scripts\tsconfig\tsconfig.json for example. Also what do we mean by install the @type ? Sorry , new to all of this .

Answer (score 0):

For types that haven't yet made it into the standard definition file, you can [extend the interface to include the additional properties](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/01/complex-typescript-definitions-made-easy/):

```
interface Window {
    filereader: any;
}

if (window.filereader) {

}
```

If you are using a library, for example jQuery, you can [grab a ready-made definition for that](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).